# How to filter in execute query by Date range value?

Tags: range, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to made a *Query* in `executeQuery` , and I have to filter by date field, 
my code is :

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    utcDateTime dateUTC, datenullUTC;
    query q = new Query();

    QueryBuildRange qbr;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds ;
    QueryRun queryRun;

    dateUTC = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(_dateValue, 0, DateTimeUtil::getCompanyTimeZone());

    qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(MCRCustCategory) ); 

    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(MCRCustCategory, ValidTo)).value(strFmt ("> %1", dateUTC) );

    queryRun = new QueryRun (q);

    super();
}
```

In my `init` I call the *executeQuery*, but don't filter in my Form.

How to use the date in the Range ?

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a table which use [date effective](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/gg861781.aspx). You assume you have to do the selection yourself, this is not true.

Use this instead:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    this.queryBuildDataSource().validTimeStateAsOfDate(_dateValue);
    super();
}
```

If you have an interval, use this instead:

```
this.queryBuildDataSource().validTimeStateDateRange(fromDate, toDate)
```

Your code as provided in the question does not do anything at all, as the form does not use the query you build. You buildt the wrong query anyway!

This [blog post](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/10/valid-time-statedate-effective_05.html) explains it concisely.

Comment: `this.queryBuildDataSource().validateNameCharacters();`
I only have this method if I write in _executeQuery_ method form.

Comment: You have it in all datasource methods. Otherwise locate the query by other means.

Comment: What has `validateNameCharacters` to do with anything?