# How to filter by date and do a Form's query by code?

Tags: datetime, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, executequery

I have to do a Form query by code. The datasource table is *CustomVendTable*(is a custom table).
I open a *form* and in my `init` method I get the table caller :

```
public void init ()
{
  VendTable = myVendTableCaller;
  myVendTableCaller = element.args().record();
// There is a dialog and get a date by a _Dialog_ and save in a date variable
  super();
}
```

In my data source I have a build a **query**. The table in my datasource is related whit VendTable. I filter by code my *DataSource* by myVendTableCaller.RecId and variable **date** *dateByDialog* inserted in the opening *dialog*

My query is this:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
query q = new Query();
QueryBuildRange qbr;
QueryBuildDataSource qbds ;
QueryRun queryRun;

qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(CustomVendTable) );

qbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustomVendTable, ValidFrom)).value(SysQuery::value( strFmt ("<=%1 ", _dateByDialog)) ) ;
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustomVendTable, ValidTo)).value(SysQuery::value( strFmt (">=%1 ", _dateByDialog))) ;
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustomVendTable, Vendor )).value(SysQuery::value(myVendTableCaller.recId));

queryRun = new QueryRun (q);

CustomVendTable_ds.query(queryRun.query());

super();
}
```

*For information there is a *Table Relation* CustomVendTable.Vendor == VendTable.RecId

So, I have some problems! I think not to be able to make a correct *query* by date. The fields **ValidFrom - ValidTo** are *UTCdatetime* type.

1) I have to convert my _dateByDialog in UTC ? How to do ? It' s correct my query date way ?

Considering that the conversion is not impossible, my BIG problem is that by filtering by date, if I have only one record with recid same range and dates I can somehow see it, BUT if there are more record with these same characteristics (If I have 2 record) I don't see nothing! My Form Grid is void!

I have read that you should set the *Session date time* ([I'm talking about this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa571130.aspx) ) to have control over dates.

I still believe that I do not build my *Query* very well.

Do you have an idea how can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used DateTimeUtil::newDateTime and made new UTCDateTime parameters for the dates?

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/alirazatechblog/archive/2012/09/03/date-to-utcdatetime-convertion-dynamics-ax-2012

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a table which use [date effective](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/gg861781.aspx). You assume you have to do the selection yourself, this is not true.

Instead call method `validTimeStateAsOfDate` on the datasource. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34023281/4509) for details.

Comment: Also, do not build the query from scratch. Change the query build by `init` method.